# Почему круг пересекает границы Form1, если я прописал нужные условия?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int x = 50;
        int y = 50;

        int x2 = 870;
        int y2 = 130;
        int x3 = 920;
        int y3 = 40;
        int x4 = 970;
        int y4 = 130;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen whitePen = new Pen(Color.White, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(whitePen, x, y, 100, 100);
            Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, x2, y2, x3, y3);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, x3, y3, x4, y4);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, x4, y4, x2, y2);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Invalidate();
            //Столкновение с рамками экрана
            if (x <= 1 && x >= 1350)
            {
                x = -5;
            }
            else if (y <= 1 && y >= 920)
            {
                y = -5;
            }


        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            //Круг
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                x -= 5;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                x += 5;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                y -= 5;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                y += 5;
            }

            //Эллипс
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                x2 -= 5;
                x3 -= 5;
                x4 -= 5;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
            {
                x2 += 5;
                x3 += 5;
                x4 += 5;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W)
            {
                y2 -= 5;
                y3 -= 5;
                y4 -= 5;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
            {
                y2 += 5;
                y3 += 5;
                y4 += 5;
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: попробуйте прописать условия там, где вы меняете координаты, а не там, где они непонятно зачем нужны

Comment: Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/575292/198316) почитайте. Не смотря на то, что там про контролы, вашего случая это тоже касается, отрисовка всех элементов: и контролов, и эллипсов, и даже точек и линий, происходит одинаково - по правилам ограничивающего прямоугольника.